# Добавление из JTextField в JList.(использовать defaultmodel нельзя)

Tags: java

Нужно из `JTextField` добавить в `JList`. Знаю, что вроде нужен массив.

Но как правильно его написать?

```
JList capitalsList;
String[]capitals={};
private final static String newline = "\n";

public MyList() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

            textField = new JTextField(20);
            textField.addActionListener(this);

            capitalsList = new JList(capitals);
            add(capitalsList);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(capitalsList);


            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(textField, c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.weighty = 1.0;
            add(scrollPane, c);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
```

Ввод в `JList`:

```
        textField.setText("");


}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Capitals");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            frame.add(new MyList());


            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
  }
}
```